# iOS: populated NSDictionary valueForKey is returning nil

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary

I have the following NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
```

But when I try to query the dictionary using valueForKey I always get nil value. For example:

```
po [myDict valueForKey:@"value1"]
 nil
```

If query the dictionary using objectForKey everything is Ok..

```
po [myDict objectForKey:@"key1"]
value1
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting nil when I query the dictionary using valueForKey ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is passing `@"value1"` instead of `@"key1"` to `valueForKey:` a typo in your question or your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueForKey:` should only be used when you have a clear and understood need to use key-value coding. You still need to pass in a key but you are passing in a value. Since there is no key in the dictionary of `value1`, it correctly returns `nil`.

But again, don't use `valueForKey:` unless you have a proper reason.

`objectForKey:` on `key1` works because you actually have a key of `key1` in the dictionary.

If you were to call `objectForKey:@"value1"` it would also return `nil`.